# How to write condition statement to ask excel to concatenate 2 values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there any IF function, conditional statement in Excel?

There are 3 tables. I was thinking of using IF fuction. I tried " IF(J2=VLOOKUP(J2,$L$1:$G$9,2,0),CONCATENATE(E1," ", F1)). But I can't. I wonder if there are some ways that allow me to if the value of column L is to match with D1, and then spreadsheet will concatenate E1 and F1.

I have rubbish solutions. First, I do VLOOKUP twice on column L, the column M. By this way, I can match column I with both column L, M. I'd do another concatenation on column N. Then, I copy and paste into the correct column L called Full Name.
[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKppn.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say to solve this:

some ways that allow me to if the value of column L is to match with D1, and then spreadsheet will concatenate E1 and F1

is to do this:

`=IF($D$1=L1;CONCAT(E1;F1);"")`

result:
[image]

Comment: is there any formula like vlookup? because $D$1 may not always be the same as L1 but the same value would live in the column L.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it and your formula works fine? Maybe try switching the columns of your table_array so it's G to L instead of L to G? I believe lookup has to happen only in the first column of your table_array, and the col_index_num has to be to the right of the that first column. [image]